# jQuery UI Sortables - Call Sortable Event Externally

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm have the following sortable snippet (nothing fancy):

```
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(ui);
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

How would you call **beforeStop: function(event, ui) {}** outside of **sortable()** and specify the element being sorted and the target sortable list (i.e. #sortable1 or #sortable2)?

I need to be able to use **event** and **ui** objects.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean emulate the `beforeStop` event?

Comment: @NeXXeuS Yep! I want to simulate/trigger that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var handleBeforeStop = function(event, ui) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(ui);
};
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  beforeStop: handleBeforeStop,
}).disableSelection();
```

then in your code, you can do this from any arbitrary place...

```
var myEvent = {/*fill this with the event props you need*/};
handleBeforeStop(myEvent, $("#sortable1"));
```

Hope this helps, its hard to know from your question what exactly it is you're after

Comment: @jaydub : It is close. I should be able to reference the item I'm wanting to sort, this could be a <li/> element and then point that to a sortable <ul/>, in this case #sortable1 and then it will execute the beforeStop. I'm trying to accomplish this from anywhere in the code. Try and think of it as simulating/replicating the user sorting an element.

Comment: I don't think what you have for "$( this )" is what you think it will be. The scope handleDrop is running is different in the two scenarios. Check the docs to see what properties the ui param will contain, I believe you can access the droppable and dragable instances directly instead of relying on "this". Then, when you call it by hand, just mimic the same ui param.

Comment: Sorry deleted the previous comment. The most recent one is correct.

Comment: my answer in the comments still applies